# How to handle hive/avro schema evolution with new fields added in the middle of existing fields?

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

I have been told that the only way for Hive to be able to process the addition of new fields to an `avro` schema is if the new fields are added at the end of the existing fields. Currently our `avro` generation is alphabetical, so a new field could show up elsewhere in the field list.

So, can Hive handle this or not? I know next to nothing about Hive but I can see that [there are good explanations](http://getindata.com/schema-evolution-with-avro-and-hive/) of how to add new fields from `avro` but I can't seem to find any info on whether the location of the added field affects the ability of Hive to process them or not.

As an example, see below. **How could the new schema be processed into Hive?**:

**Original Schema**

```
{
"type":"record","name":"user",
   "fields":[
       {"name":"bday","type":"string"},
       {"name":"id","type":"long"},
       {"name":"name","type":"string"}
   ]
}
```

**New Schema (Added field in alphabetical order)**

```
{
"type":"record","name":"user",
   "fields":[
       {"name":"bday","type":"string"},
       {"name":"id","type":"long"},
       {"name":"gender","type":"string"},
       {"name":"name","type":"string"}
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Hive can handle this because it's the way Avro [works](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Schema+Resolution):

> if both are records:
>   the ordering of fields may be different: **fields are matched by name**

---

That's possible because all Avro files also include a schema used to write the data, *writer's schema*. 
So, when you change the schema in Hive (e.g. by modifying `avro.schema.url` underlying file), you change the *reader's schema*. But all existing files and their writer's schemas remain untouched.

And yes, for all new fields added you have to provide a default value (using `"default":...`) regardless of fields ordering. Otherwise, the reader (Hive) won't be able to parse files written with original schema.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. We ultimately did end up having to add the default values so that our client could support our files.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported. You have to take care about add a default value for the new fields to be able to read the data that was written  with the older schema.

Comment: Can you expand some on this? How would this be accomplished? Do you have any examples or documentation to back this up? Thanks.